# Remove gridheader rollover in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mx

Is there a way to remove the grid header rollover in flex while still maintaining a sortable header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the rollover color one trick would be to set the rolloever color to be the same as the grid header color in your style sheet or inline in your MXML:

```
DataGrid {
    headerColors: #0079FF, #0079FF;     
}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. I don't have a good example for you, but you are going to need to extend some classes in order to override the rollover color, best bet is to find out how the header rollover color is assigned and give it an alpha of 0.